# apacite - parentheses color not changing

Tags: apacite

I use texmake with Windows 8. Everything working except parentheses color of citation is not changing to blue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
This is cold \cite <see e.g.>{admassu2019trade}
This is cold \citeA{admassu2019trade} as well as \citeA{anderson2003gravity}.

\bibliography{References}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By changing the parentheses color to blue, do you mean 'make them part of the hyperlink'? If yes, then maybe this is not always a good idea, for example when you have two citations in one, like `\cite{Jones,Smith}` which is rendered as (Jones, 2001; Smith, 1995) for example, then the parentheses do not really belong to either citation. If you just mean 'make them blue, but not part of the link' then it would be a bit easier, but that is probably not what you want?

Comment: I just want them the same color as the citation text inside. For that I tried \bibpunct but it did not worked somehow!

Comment: You can do that (`\renewcommand{\BBOP}{\textcolor{blue}{(}}\renewcommand{\BBCP}{\textcolor{blue}{)}}` after `\begin{document}`) but it looks strange for the first citation because _see e.g._ is not blue.

Comment: Strange! Now I see parentheses turning blue but another problem: It says "I couldn't open file name `References.aux' ".
This is my first document I am preparing with latex. I could not understand one thing that on one hand latex is regarded as stronger tool as compared to MS Word, and very popular. On the other hand, there is no clear simple way to execute a common task like citation. And it seems to be very sensitive and kind of unstable. Earlier, I was using Endnote and that is so clean and stable. Or, maybe it is just because I am a new user of latex with my limited skills.

Comment: LaTeX takes a bit of getting used to - I'm sure when you started with Word there were also many things that you had to learn how to do :) for the specific problem with the `.aux` file it may help to delete that file manually in your file manager, then LaTeX will recreate it at the next run and load it at the run after that.

Comment: I deleted everything except demo.tex and References.bib files in the folder. Run the the Quick Build for demo.tex, run the BibTex, then run the Quick Build for demo.tex and so ... but the pdf prints with question marks as the problem persists: I couldn't open file name `References.aux'